# OneSignal: How to target notification receiver users by tag values?

Tags: java, android, onesignal

`OneSignal` provides segmentation from which we can make segments of users according to some `key-value` pairs received from client application as a tag.

But In my case, I've got a lot of `value`s but a single `key`. Now I cannot go through every `value` and make a segment out of it. And on top of that, any user can make another new group of people also (who all have their another `value` to the single `key`), So I cannot make a segment of that.

All in all, what I need is I want to send a notification to those users who have `value` remote (*just an example*) to the `key` topic. So, how can I do so?

Here I don't want to target notification receivers by segment instead I want to target them by tag values.

For instance, let's say that I have an application where a lot of discussions goes on, now some users are associated with x discussion and some other are associated with y discussion. The users who are associated with x discussion send a tag to `OneSignal` where the `key` is topic and `value` is x. And so do the users associated with y.

If there were only two discussions then I can easily make two segments, but it is not like that, anyone can create a new discussion, So it becomes difficult to make a new segment for each and every discussion almost impossible.

Now, when any new message gets posted in any discussion (* let's take an example of x*) then, I want to send the users associated with the x discussion a notification about the message.

So, I want to target those users who are associated with discussion x (*i.e. has `topic` = `x`*). How can I do so?

I've not created any segment for that, what I have is just the key and value.

Comment: I think't it wold be better if you added some example because the question as it is, is difficult to follow.

Comment: @Juan check out

Comment: I think you should be targetting indiviual users directly. Keeping on the application side the relation betwee what user is following what question. When there is an update, you send the notification to each user. It seems to me it even would be less of burden that having to mange questions as topics. Apart from that,  in a site like,  SO there would be millions of topics...

Comment: I like your idea, btw that app is just an example to make everyone understand what my question is. The real app is entirely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to treat questions as topics in order to notify updates to the users following the questions would be to manage the relation between the questions an the users are following them in the application itself.

When a question is updated, fetch the users related to the question, and send them individual notifications.

This, to my understanding, would be easier to manage than trying to manage the questions as topics.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me!